# Display retail stores in shopping mall - GoogleMaps Indoor

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm testing the google maps SDK on iOS (I'm using the latest version).
I'm using the provided examples form google in order to test the indoor navigation functionality.

I don't know why, but when I look at a shopping mall on my example app, I see the indoor plans but no the retail stores located in it, but when using the Google Maps native iphone app, I can see the retail stores.

P.S: I'm testing on a real device - not on the simulator.

My code:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:32.074492
                                                        longitude:34.791458
                                                             zoom:18];

mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.indoorEnabled = YES;
mapView_.settings.indoorPicker = YES;
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
mapView_.delegate=self;
mapView_.indoorDisplay.delegate=self;

// Ask for My Location data after the map has already been added to the UI.

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
});

self.view = mapView_;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use Places API for in order to show store. You can sign up for one with a public beta over [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/). Places API shows detailed information about 100 million places across a wide range of categories, from the same database as Google Maps and Google+.